# Use case for the curve modifier

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I'm trying to model a doorknob. Here's the reference image:

[image]

I thought this was a good chance to use a curve modifier. But it seemed to me that the workflow with the curve modifier is actually more complicated than without it. I had to edit the mesh a lot after applying the curve modifier to make it look like a reference, especially in the widest round part of the doorknob. How to properly model something like this, use a curve modifier, or add a cube and extrude step by step it manually, or something else? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello :). Curve modifier seems like overkill for such a simple shape. Proportional editing or a subdivision surface modeling seems more appropriate :).

Comment: I feel like there is an undercurrent here of "when the heck does one use the curve modifier if not here?" For me, I tend to use it when I'm modelling from my imagination rather than when I'm working from a reference.

It's good to keep everything constructive as much as possible when prototyping, etc.

Comment: @jwrush You get my point :) Thank you for sharing your experience!

Comment: @Jachym Michal Thank you! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use your picture as an *Image Reference*.

You can create a circle (in the *Operator* box, on the bottom left of your 3D view, choose for example 8 vertices), extrude inwards with <kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd> and <kbd>S</kbd> to scale, then fill the central hole with <kbd>F</kbd>:

[image]

Select 2 edges on the right of the circle and extrude towards the right with <kbd>E</kbd>:

[image]

Select all and extrude on the Y direction with <kbd>E</kbd> (by default it should extrude along the normals and the normals are pointing towards the Y direction so you should not need to specify Y after <kbd>E</kbd>):

[image]

Extrude again:

[image]

etc...

Comment: Nice, but ... Your first Extrude needs a bit more explanation, as you don't explain how each segment is along a different angle.  @jane_miller looks like a newbie or one who doesn't post/visit here often.

Comment: Ok I've tried to bring some precisions

Comment: @moonboots Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation! Actually I have a little bit of experience in modeling. Right now I'm trying to improve my skills by making different objects. I'm just often not sure I'm picking the right way to model things, and I really want to get better at it.

Comment: @james_t Thanks for your kind reply!

Comment: @jane_miller: please check moonboots answer as "right" (tap on checkmark left to his answer) if it helped you, because he helped you and had some time effort and he deserves it ;) Comments are nice of course, but the checkmarks show people who have the same question as you and read it to know "this answer helped her". Thanks.

Comment: @Chris Done :) Sorry, I forgot about that!